# Setting up a Server Environment in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I wanted to set up a Tomcat Environment in Eclipse to run my SOAP project . While doing so i get an error called

***The Tomcat v6.0 Server server does not support the service project SimpleSOAPExample.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error generally occurs when your web module version is higher than the one tomcat supports You can try this- lower your web module version, Create new "Dynamic Web Project". In the project wizard you should change "Dynamic web module version" from 3 to lower(2.2, 2.3, 2.4 or 2.5). I generally work with 2.5. Tomcat 6 is not compatible with module version 3. If you however require to work on V3.0 switch to tomcat 7.

Comment: thank u it worked ! Once i execute i get another error on the server **description: The requested resource () is not available **

Comment: You're welcome. Please post the new issue as a separate question, as it seems unrelated to this.